# Can i have right carousel in ionic slide box?

Tags: ionic-framework

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnhMY.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIYZm.png
I took this from a site and I'm trying to have one like this only on the right side of my page. In my page i have a header,footer and in the content area i have this ion slide box where the images will be sliding one after the other. so i want a right carousel like in the second image link..

Comment: Have you looked at the `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate` service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Ionic Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSlideBoxDelegate/) you can. The `ion-slide-box`element comes with the `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate` service that provides helper methods to control the slides.One of these helper functions on the service is `next()`. this allows you to go to next slide on a button click event.All you need to do is position your button as required and use the code as below(slightly modified from documentation).

USAGE:

```
//Your view
    <ion-view>
      <ion-slide-box>
        <ion-slide>
          <div class="box blue">
            Slide 1
          </div>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <div class="box red">
            Slide 2!
          </div>
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slide-box>
//Your button
<button ng-click="nextSlide()" class = "button-icon ion-chevron-right"></button>

    </ion-view>

//In your controller

    function MyCtrl($scope, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
      $scope.nextSlide = function() {
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
      }
    }
```